# How can I create a PDF with a different full-page background image for each page, perhaps using Word 2011 or OpenOffice Writer 4?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, openoffice

I've searched and seen how I can create a watermarked Word document with a background image that applies to the whole document. What I have not yet found, for Mac Word, 2011 OpenOffice 4.x, or other PDF-generating software, is a way to specify a different image each page.

If I have a novella, and I want to include it in a Word document with basic word processor-based formatting, what are my options for specifying a different background for each page?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to add an image in the center of a page like normal, use the "wash out" coloring options, and send the image to the back. That should create the desired look and work across different word processors.